# HighCharts - Can't scroll page when cursor is on column chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using highcharts-react-official version 3.0.0 and highcharts version 8.1.2 in my web application.

My problem is that the user can't scroll the page, using the mouse wheel, when the mouse cursor is positioned on a column chart. My page is full of charts, so in order to scroll, the user has to be careful to put the mouse cursor somewhere on the page where there isn't a chart.

Can I fix this somehow? I want the user to be able to scroll everywhere on the page.

I tried stuff like `chart.scrollablePlotArea` and `followTouchMove: false`. Didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Jón Gunnar, This problem doesn't seem to be related to Highcharts. Please check this simple demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-4cy1eg?file=/demo.jsx - scrolling works as expected. Could you reproduce the problem in a live example?

Comment: Yes, it is. Perhaps you're using a different version. And unfortunately I don't know how to do those live examples. I'm asking here just to check out if anyone here knows what the problem might be and/or has run into similar problems.

Comment: Ok, I take it back slightly at least :) . I copy pasted your code and that worked. But I wonder if anyone here knows what property/option stops the scroll?

Comment: Ok, I believe I found out myself why it's not working. onmousewheel event is handled, in which event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() are called. I'll close this if this is the case ... . @ppotaczek, your code was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself why it's not working. onmousewheel event is handled, in which event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() are called.